# Google Apps Script Grid Column Text Align to Center

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-sites

```
grid.setWidth('600px')
  .setBorderWidth(0)
  .setCellPadding(10)
  .setCellSpacing(0)
  .setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel(''))
  .setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel('Not Qualified'))
  .setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel('Directed'))
  .setWidget(0, 3, app.createLabel('Skilled'))

  .setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Manager'))
  .setWidget(1, 1, pmRadio1) // Radio Button
  .setWidget(1, 2, pmRadio2) // Radio Button
  .setWidget(1, 3, pmRadio3) // Radio Button

  .setColumnStyleAttribute(1, "text-align", "center")
```

I want to center align the radio buttons to the header label "Manager". I have given the `text-align` as `center` in `setColumnStyleAttribute`. But its not working.

Tried the below code also. Not working

```
  var tt = {'text-align': 'center'}
  grid.setColumnStyleAttributes(1, tt)
```

First Column should be left aligned & Sencond column should Center aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation for setColumnStyleAttribute() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/grid#setColumnStyleAttribute(Integer,String,String)): the attribute name must be in **camelCase**, so use `'textAlign'` instead of `'text-align'`.

**UPDATE**

Since you are populating grid cells with label widgets, you have to apply styles to individual labels using `.setStyleAttribute('textAlign', 'center')`, or to the cells containing the labels/widgets using grid's [`.setStyleAttributes(row, column, {attributes})`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/grid#setStyleAttributes(Integer,Integer,Object)) method.

The `.setColumnStyleAttribute(column, attribute, value)` method you are trying to use creates a `<colgroup>` element in the grid's table, and applies styles to specified `<col>` element in the colgroup. However, [most of style attributes are not supported in `<col>` element in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp), including `text-align` attribute - that's why you see no effect of using this method.

Comment: Try just `align` instead of `textAlign`. If I remember correctly (have not used UI Service in a long while), the UI Grid creates a `<table>` html element, so column will be `<td>` elements, which use `align` attribute.

Comment: Doh! You are populating your grid with labels, which create `<div>` elements inside grid's cells! You have to apply `.setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "center")` to your label widgets, not grid's column. Alternatively, populate your grid with plain text using `.setText()` method instead of `.setWidget()`  - then you can apply styles to grid columns.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include above explanation